# How can I accept ssl and partially blocked content in Firefox with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Any idea how to get what works in chrome:
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')

To work in firefox webdrive and in IE ?
I have been trying everything I could find with no luck..

IE will kick the ssl page where I need to accept it... mind you trying to click the button with selenium does not work it shows like the web window does not exists for it yet...

In firefox I can get the page but mixed content is blocked.. so I get only text

I spend so much time without success on this, so last resort I'm asking here. ( There is plenty of "solutions" around but seems like they are old... )

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, IE web driver is broken ( seems like for long time ) - so I have abandoned IE altogether. ( all it can do is lunch IE browser, and lunch page, than it loose connection to it and you can't even do driver.close() )

Firefox - Well still no luck there

Tried:

```
ff_options = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
ff_options['marionette'] = True
ff_options['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
```

But seems to have no effect, also I could not find how to allow mixed content, there is so little documentation for the options :(